# How to fix “Permission denied” when trying to edit a file on aws server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a PHP file on AWS linux server. The address is `/var/app/***/a.php`. When I try to edit the file using WinSCP, I get the permission denied error.

I tried to access the rights to edit using this command: `chown -R root:root /var/app` with and without `sudo`, but it didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Try to edit file with `sudo`, e.g. `sudo vim /var/app/***/a.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `chown` command you are using is setting the permissions to `root:root` so if you're following good practices and connecting via WinSCP with a non-root user (such as `ubuntu`), you should actually be using something like `chown -R ubuntu /var/app` which will change the ownership to that of you're day-to-day user.